# Mostrar grafico en template AdminTLE Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en una app de Django para control de facturas. Tengo instalado el tema AdminLTE en mi panel de administracion y no consigo generar una página con la grafica de las facturas. No me carga mi archivo html que tengo dentro la carpeta factures/templates/factures/grafiques.html sino que me carga el generico del template de AdminLTE. Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Este es mi modelo de Factura:

```
class Factura(models.Model):
id_factura = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nom_factura = models.CharField(max_length=100)
nom_facturador = models.ForeignKey(Facturador, verbose_name="Empresa", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
data_factura = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
data_modificacio = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
pagament_factura  = models.BooleanField()
objectes_factura = models.ManyToManyField(Objectes, verbose_name="Productes")
total_factura = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Total", decimal_places=4, max_digits=4, default=0)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Factura"
    verbose_name_plural = "Factures"
    ordering = ["-data_factura"]

def __str__(self):
    return self.nom_factura
```

Esta es mi llamada en urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from web import views as webplei
from factures import views as facturesView

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', webplei.inici, name="inici"),
   path('plei', webplei.plei, name="plei"),
   path('admin/factures/', facturesView.iniciFactures, name="factures"),
]
```

Y este es mi archivo views:

```
# Create your views here.
def iniciFactures(request):
    return render(request, "factures/grafiques.html",    {'data':get_graph_sales_year_month()})

def get_graph_sales_year_month():
    data = []
    try:
        for m in range(1, 13):
            total = Factura.objects.filter(year =ExtractYear('data_factura') ,m=ExtractMonth('data_factura')).aggregate(r=Coalesce(Sum('total'), 0)).get('r')
        data.append(float(total))
    except:
        pass
    return data
```

Este es mi archivo grafiques.html, la parte donde cargo el javascript y la variable de data:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Porcentaje de venta',
            showInLegend: false,
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: {{ data }}
        }]
```